# Changing status of Published posts which have less Content to "Draft"

Tags: menus, query, wpdb, post-status, draft

```
function draftpost(){
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$prefix."posts SET post_status='draft' WHERE LENGTH( post_content ) <500");
}
add_action('publish_post', 'draftpost');
```

This code is working Fine for changing Published Items to Draft.

Issue is that this code removes my Custom Menu and make all Items in Menu to PENDING.
How can I solve this?

Comment: are you trying to change all existing posts with "less content" to draft, or just the post that is being published?

Comment: I am trying to change all posts with less content to draft and this action happens when user is posting new post.